# Finding out the reason for ban

Tags: support, post-ban

After some months I got back to [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) to ask a question there.

Now I get this really disturbing message:

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See [the Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to learn more.

As far as I remember I always had a positiv statistic at programmers, so I do not see any reason for some kind of ban. From what I can see in my profile, there are only positive questions / answers.

From my profile I can see that I have 2 questions asked. One positive, one deleted because it seemed to be offtopic (which I tried to discuss, because the question is legit from what the rules tell).

So, 1 good question, 1 closed question and 1 good answer... this gets me banned?

So, my question is very simple:

How can I find out what on the world led to that ban?

Comment: I migrated the question here, as it is specific to Programmers. Nothing to do with the network as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

You have asked 4 questions on the site.

3 of them are deleted, all 3 have downvotes to them. The remaining question is not stellar (single upvote).

Looks like they mostly don't follow the on-topic/off-topic rules laid out in the help center, so not that surprising.

Comment: Okay then, I just have seen one deleted question. Fine that the quality hooks work well on this site. From the remaining question I really do not see why it should be off-topic, but it is okay now.